# UITableViewCell : initWithFrame : reuseIdentifier deprecated

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm having trouble with creating my UITableViewCell since UITableViewCell : initWithFrame : reuseIdentifier is deprecated. Please stay with me, I've looked over other questions about this but couldn't find them helpful. So here is my function.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCellObject *cell = (MyCellObject *)[tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[ChatCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cellid"] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

As I read from other questions, I tried:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCellObject *cell = (MyCellObject *)[tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyCellObject alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellid"] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But my cell won't display its text then. I can tap the cell row and it becomes selects, but no visible text. Because my cell text is handled in my `MyCellObject` and not `cell.textLabel.text`, I need to init the cell with a frame (`initWithFrame`), but I also need to init it with an identifier (`reuseIdentifier`).

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't think `MyCellObject` as everything worked before the above function was deprecated. Here's part of `MyCellObject` and it is derived from `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self == nil) {
        return nil;
    } 
    tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    tagLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tagLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    tagLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;    
    tagLabel.opaque = YES;

    [self addSubview:tagLabel];
}
```

The reason I have it setup that was is so I can "micro manage" the text in it a little more.

Comment: Could you put more information about how you set your textLabel and how is the MyCellObject look like. I don't think the problem is related with the code you posted.

Comment: I read somewhere that the new `-dequeue...` method has been changed and now it never returns `nil`: If no cell is available for reuse, it allocates one. So the nil check becomes unnecessary.

Comment: use ' MyCellObject *cell = (MyCellObject *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"]; '

Answer (score 0):

1) You haven't set the cell title. So you won't see any text on the cell. Here you have used a `UITableViewCell` class. So you will need to add a label to the cell in the `storyboard` and set outlet to `UITableViewCell` in your case which is `MyCellObject` class. Then you will be able to set text to that label.

2) You can just use

> MyCellObject *cell = (MyCellObject *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];

Try this..

> -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>
> MyCellObject *cell = (MyCellObject *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
>
> cell.myCustomLabel.text = @"Your text";
>
> return cell;
>
> }